# How to store data in a form so on page refresh the fields are still populated

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, local-storage

I'm new to S.O and javascript. I am working on a final year project for a e-commerce website and have ran into a dead end on saving data from a form into local storage. My code is below, i really don't see where i have gone wrong. all help is appreciated.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  // Check for LocalStorage support.
  if (localStorage) {
    // Populate the form fields
    populateForm();

    // Get the form
    var form = document.getElementById("franchiseForm");

    // Event listener for when the bookings form is submitted.
    form.addEventListener("submit", function(e) {
      saveData(form);
    });
  }
}

// Save the form data in LocalStorage.
function saveData() {
  //fetch sava(data)
  var fran_name = document.getElemenyById("fran_name"); 
  var name = document.getElemenyById("name");
  var address1 = document.getElemenyById("address1");
  var address2 = document.getElemenyById("address2");
  var city = document.getElemenyById("city");
  var pcode = document.getElemenyById("pcode");
  var phone = document.getElemenyById("phone");

  //store the values
  localStorage.setItem("fran_name", fran_name.value);
  localStorage.setItem("name", name.value);
  localStorage.setItem("address1", address1.value);
  localStorage.setItem("address2", address2.value);
  localStorage.setItem("city", city.value);
  localStorage.setItem("pcode", pcode.value);
  localStorage.setItem("phone", phone.value);
}

// Attempt to populate the form using data stored in LocalStorage.
function populateForm() {
  // Fetch the input elements.
  var fran_name = document.getElemenyById("fran_name"); 
  var name = document.getElemenyById("name");
  var address1 = document.getElemenyById("address1");
  var address2 = document.getElemenyById("address2");
  var city = document.getElemenyById("city");
  var pcode = document.getElemenyById("pcode");
  var phone = document.getElemenyById("phone");

  //retrieve saved data and update the values of the form.
  if (localStorage.getItem("fran_name") != null) {
    name.value = localStorage.getItem("fran_name");
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem("name") != null) {
    phone.value = localStorage.getItem("name");
  }

  if (localStorage.getItem("address1") != null) {
    email.value = localStorage.getItem("address1");
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("address2") != null) {
    email.value = localStorage.getItem("address12");
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("city") != null) {
    email.value = localStorage.getItem("city");
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("pcode") != null) {
    email.value = localStorage.getItem("pcode");
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("phone") != null) {
    email.value = localStorage.getItem("phone");
  }
}
window.onload = function(){
  if (localstorage){
    //populate the form fields
    populateform(form);
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="section">  

  <form id="franchiseForm" action ="Order_confirmation.php" method="POST">

    <div class="field">
      <label for="fran_name">Franchise Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="franchise_name" id="fran_name" placeholder="e.g One Delivery Leeds" pattern="[a-zA-Z]" 
             autofocus required tabindex="1">
      <br>

      <label for="name">Name</label>
      <input type="text" name="franc_name" id="name" placeholder="Joe Blogs" required tabindex="2">
      <br>

      <label for="address"> Address</label>
      <input type="text" name="franc_address" id="address1" placeholder="Address Line 1" tanindex="3">
      <input type="text"  id="address2" placeholder="Address Line 2" tabindex="4">
      <input type="text"  id="city" placeholder="Town/City" tabindex="5">
      <input type="text"  id="pcode" placeholder="Postcode" tabindex="6">
      <br>

      <label for="phone" > Phone Number</label>
      <input type="tel" name="franc_phone" id="phone" placeholder="Customer service number" min="10" maxlength="11" pattern="[0-9]{3}[-][0-9]{4}[-][0-9]{4}" 
             required title="Please provide your customer service number in the following format: 000-0000-0000" tabindex="7">
    </div>

    <div class="field">
      <input type="submit" id="submit" value="submit">
    </div>
  </form>
```

Comment: why dont you use cookies?, see this: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: email.value?  where is that in your HTML.  I haven't run this through fiddle or anything, but at first glance you have 5 things being set to one ID that i can't seem to find in your markup.

Comment: @Shocklo local storage is a much better solution than cookies for such use cases.

Comment: Is the problem getting the data into localstorage or out and into the form?

Comment: You also have a item named address12, i'm assuming typo?

Comment: Thanks for pointing the email value out, i didn't even see that

Comment: Hi everyone thank you so much! i found my errors,  thank to all your help my populayeForm(); variable, was meant to be populateForm(form); now it work perfectly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, not in your code you use:

```
document.getElemenyById(...);
localstorage.setItem()
```

instead of (note the Elemeny vs. Element, s vs. S):

```
document.getElementById(...);
localStorage.setItem();
```

---

As for a full solution:

You can use various local storage to store this data in the browser.
You can  do something like this when the page is about to reload:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    var fran_name = document.getElementById("fran_name"); 
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    // ...

    localStorage.setItem("fran_name", fran_name.value);
    localStorage.setItem("name", name.value);
    // ...
}
```

`localstorage` works synchronously so this will work here.

At page load you can check:

```
window.onload = function() {

    var name = localStorage.getItem(name);
    if (name !== null) document.getElemenyById("name").value = name;

    // ...
}
```

`getItem` will return null` if the data does not exist.

Use `sessionStorage` instead of `localStorage` if you want to store temporarily - until the browser is closed.

---

Here's a simplified version of your form, with complete working code. save it as a .html file:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // For saving data:
            window.onbeforeunload = function() {
                var name = document.getElementById("name");
                // ...
                localStorage.setItem("name", name.value);
                // ...
            }
            // For loading data:
            window.onload = function() {
                var name = localStorage.getItem(name);
                if (name !== null) document.getElemenyById("name").value = name;
                // ...
            }
        </script>
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="section">
            <form id="franchiseForm" action="Order_confirmation.php" method="POST">
                <div class="field">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" name="franc_name" id="name" placeholder="Joe Blogs" required tabindex="2">
                    <br>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5):

The main thing is, check your console for this error:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: `localstorage` is not defined.

Change your code. It is `localStorage` and not `localstorage`. That's a capital `S`.

And a big mistake here. It is `getElementById` and not `getElemenyById`:

```
  var fran_name = document.getElemenyById("fran_name"); 
  var name = document.getElemenyById("name");
  var address1 = document.getElemenyById("address1");
  var address2 = document.getElemenyById("address2");
  var city = document.getElemenyById("city");
  var pcode = document.getElemenyById("pcode");
  var phone = document.getElemenyById("phone");
```

You have too many mistakes! `Elemeny` != `Element`.

Looks like this is stopping your code from executing:

```
  if (localStorage.getItem("address1") != null) {
    email.value = localStorage.getItem("address1");
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("address2") != null) {
    email.value = localStorage.getItem("address12");
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("city") != null) {
    email.value = localStorage.getItem("city");
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("pcode") != null) {
    email.value = localStorage.getItem("pcode");
  }
  if (localStorage.getItem("phone") != null) {
    email.value = localStorage.getItem("phone");
  }
```

You don't have a variable named `email`. And moreover, you are trying to set the value of an undefined element variable `email`, which doesn't have a property named `value`, that prevents all your scripts from executing.

Comment: Thank you so much i didn't even see those mistakes!!! Im going to fix this and see if it works

Comment: @jerneva Please make sure you check the console.

Comment: I have corrected my errors i will check the console once i charge my laptop lol

Comment: the console says it can't find the element populate form

Comment: Right.. So you have a lot of mistakes. Can you create the same in [plunker](https://plnkr.co) by adding all your contents?

Comment: Ive sorted the issue , once i resolved all the errors it was the  populateForm(); variable, it needed to be  populateForm(form);

Comment: Yes, right. Would you please mind accepting my answer now? @jerneva?

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to use JQuery and JQuery Cookie, you can save the data in a cookie:

```
var frn = $(#fran_name).val();
$.cookie("fran_name", frn);
```

Then on pageload you get the cookie data and then insert it into the field:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var cookie = $.cookie("fran_name");
    $('#fran_name').val(cookie);
});
```